# $G$-set are groupoids of a fibred category

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

> Take the category of all G-sets for different groups $G$. 
>   Each $G$-set is the groupoid $G \times \Omega \to \Omega$ (the first projection is the source and the action map is the target).

I am not sure how to understand this statement. One way to understand it is the following:

Denote

$\mathcal D:=\{p| G \times \Omega \xrightarrow[]{p}  G\}$

$\mathcal C:=\{f| G \times \Omega \xrightarrow[]{f}  \Omega\}$

From the statement, we deduce that $\mathcal D$ is a fibred in groupoids over $\mathcal C$.

If the above is correct, Can we clearly describe the functor $F:\mathcal D\to \mathcal C$?

My appologies if the question is not clear enough, it isn't either in my mind.

Comment: Where does the statement come from? It is hard to know what it means without any context.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree generally that the question is sort of unclear. In particular, $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ in your question are the same, except that you've renamed a variable, which doesn't really change what they are in any meaningful sense.

That said, I can explain the statement.

Let's start with

> Each $G$-set is the groupoid $G\times \Omega\to \Omega$ (the first projection is the source, and the action map is the target).

I assume $\Omega$ is a $G$-set here, otherwise this doesn't make sense.

**Background on internal groupoids/categories**

Recall that an internal category to $\mathbf{Set}$ is a set $M$ of morphisms, a set $O$ of objects, and three maps, $s,t : M\to O$ that specify the source and target of each morphism, and $i : O\to M$ that picks out the identity morphism for each object. 
There should also be a composition morphism $\mu : M\times_{s,O,t} M \to M$ (where the fiber product over $O$ is taken with respect to $s$ in the first variable and $t$ in the second) such that all of the axioms defining a category hold.

An internal groupoid has one more morphism, inversion, $\tau : M \to M$ that picks out the inverse of each morphism. This should also satisfy the appropriate axioms.

**An interpretation of this statement**

The parenthetical is saying that a $G$-set $\Omega$ defines an internal groupoid.
The morphism set is $G\times \Omega$, the object set is $\Omega$,
the source morphism $s:G\times \Omega\to \Omega$ is the projection onto $\Omega$ (which is the second projection, unless the source is $0$-indexing, but this is the only thing that makes sense).
The target morphism $t:G\times \Omega\to \Omega$ is the action map, $(g,m)\mapsto gm$.
The identity morphism, composition, and inversion are left unspecified, but they are 
$i(m) = (1,m)$, where $1$ is the identity in $G$,
$\mu : G\times G\times \Omega \to G\times \Omega$ is $\mu(g,h,m)=(gh,m)$,
and $\tau(g,m) = (g^{-1},gm)$.

**A more intuitive interpretation of the same groupoid**

I think it's easier to say that the groupoid of $\Omega$, sometimes written as $B\Omega$, has objects $\Omega$ and if $x,y\in\Omega$, then the morphisms are given by
$$B\Omega(x,y) = \{g\in G: gx=y \}.$$
Then it's pretty intuitive how identities and composition work and that this forms a groupoid.

**Fibered categories?**

From your question it seems that the context here has to do with fibered categories.

The fibered category in this context is given in the first sentence

> Take the category of all $G$-sets for different groups $G$.

My assumption is that this category has objects pairs $(G,M)$ with $G$ a group, $M$ a $G$-set, and morphisms
$(\phi,f) : (G,M)\to (H,N)$ pairs with $\phi:G\to H$ a homomorphism of groups and 
$f:M\to N$ a function satisfying 
$f(gm) = \phi(g)f(m)$.

Then this category is fibered over the category of groups, with projection 
$(G,M)\mapsto G$.

There's not enough context for me to relate the first sentence to the second sentence. The second sentence appears to be going into some specifics about $G$-sets before returning to the category of all $G$-sets for all groups later.

Answer (score 2):

In a groupoid (generalization of a group), the set of morphisms consist of *sources* and *targets*. A groupoid is a small category.  See "Groupoid - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid

.The $G$-sets do indeed form a category, with the notion of morphisms outlined here: "Group action - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

The morphisms are maps $\phi:X\to Y$ satisfying $\phi(gx)=g\phi(x)$, given two $G$-sets.

The $G$-set morphisms are also called *equivariant maps*, or *$G$-maps*.

So, we have the objects, the morphisms, and then comes the usual notion of functor.

Fibered categories have to do with "descent theory" and pullbacks of functors.  For more see here"Fibred category - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibred_category